# assigning variable to href from beautifull soap

Tags: python

I want to assign every `href` I find with `beautifulsoup` to variable. For example 
`link1, link2, link3 ...`.
my function look like this now

```
def board_list():
    html = driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'board-tile'}):
        href = driver.current_url+link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        print(title)
        print(href)
```

Comment: You should use a Dictionary!

Comment: You really don't want to create a bunch of variables named `link1`, `link2`, etc. What would you do with those variables? What you want to do is create a list, like `links = []`, and then `links.append(href)`. That, you can do something with—like `for link in links:`.